# "git config --list" not showing output in terminal?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, vmware, git

Hi guys I'm running Ubuntu inside VMware and I have installed Git however after inserting both user name and email when I run "git config --list" there's no output? like nothing at all.

Anyone encountered the same problem? Thank you.

Comment: Is the directory where you're running this actually a git working tree (is there a `.git` directory in it)?

Comment: Share the output of the command upon execution. As @steeldriver suggests, it is most probably that you are executing the command in the wrong directory.

Comment: The directory is the root directory and as I mentioned there’s no output none it’s just takes me to the next line ready for a new input